# What would happen if the data sending speed of the MOSI line (from the master) is too high for the slave in the Serial Peripheral Interface?

Tags: spi, communication

After searching on internet, I think this is called back pressure, but I couldn't find a good explanation. It would be really helpful if you could explain it by making a waveform.
Thanks in advance

Comment: SPI does not implement any kind of back pressure at this level. This is unlike I2C which can implement "clock stretching" to allow the target device to hold off the master.

Answer (score 3):

MOSI is sampled on the rising or falling edge of the SCLK signal.  There are additional requirements for MOSI to be stable for some interval before the edge on the SCLK signal.  If this timing requirement is not met, the slave may latch the MOSI signal while it is still in transition which would result in the value of the previous bit being used for the current sample (only an issue when the previous bit is different than the current one).

There is often some margin in these timing requirements (they guarantee accurate reception) so you might get away with it under some conditions and data transfer might be error prone in other conditions.  The input of the slave has capacitance as does the trace and any other parasitics in the signal path.  The value of this capacitance may change with temperature and humidity, how close your hand is to the board, etc etc etc.

Comment: In other words, if you violate the timing specs, it may work , it may not work, or it may work part of the time. No way to know without more data.